# Core dump on BLOB insert in informix via ODBC

Tags: c++, c, odbc, informix

Connecting to version 11.50 version of IDS with transaction logging turned on:

```
onstat -version
Program Name:   onstat
Build Version:  11.50.UC5XE
Build Number:   N104
Build Host:     ku
Build OS:       Linux kernel-2.6.9-34.ELsmp glibc-2.3.4-2.19 compat-glibc-2.3.2-95.30
Build Date:     Thu Jul 15 12:44:25 CDT 2010
GLS Version:    glslib-4.50.UC6
```

Using UnixODBC 2.2.11 over the 3.50UC8 version of the Connect drivers, on either the same system as the IDS instance (RHEL 4.8 32-bit) or a remote system running CentOS 4.8 32-bit. I get a segfault whenever I attempt to insert a BLOB into the database.

Here's the example code demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

#define CONNECTION_STRING "<valid connection string>"

#define CREATE_TABLE "CREATE TABLE blob_test(id SERIAL, test BLOB)"
#define INSERT_BLOB "INSERT INTO blob_test(test) VALUES(?)"

#define BLOB_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, const char ** args) {
    printf("Informix ODBC BLOB test.\n");

    int exitCode = 0;

    SQLHENV henv;
    SQLHDBC hdbc;
    SQLHSTMT hstmt;
    SQLLEN ind;
    SQLRETURN ret;

    char data[BLOB_SIZE];
    char * paramData = NULL;

    // Allocate environment handle
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv))) {
        printf("Failed to allocate environment handle.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))) {
        printf("Failed to initialize environment handle.\n");
        goto cleanup_env;
    }

    // Connect
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc))) {
        printf("Failed to allocate connection handle.\n");
        goto cleanup_env;
    }

    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLDriverConnectA(hdbc, NULL, 
            (SQLCHAR *)CONNECTION_STRING, SQL_NTS, 
            NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE))) {
        printf("Failed to connect.\n");
        goto cleanup_dbc;
    }
    printf("Connected.\n");

    // Allocate statement
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt))) {
        printf("Failed to allocate statement handle.\n");
        goto disconnect;
    }

    //Create table
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLExecDirectA(hstmt, 
            (SQLCHAR *)CREATE_TABLE, strlen(CREATE_TABLE)))) {
        printf("Failed to create table.\n");
        //continue anyway
    } else {
        printf("Created test table.\n");
    }

    //Prepare data
    memset(data, 0, BLOB_SIZE);

    //Prepare statement
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLPrepareA(hstmt, 
            (SQLCHAR *)INSERT_BLOB, strlen(INSERT_BLOB)))) {
        printf("Failed to prepare statement.\n");
        goto cleanup_stmt;
    }

    //Bind data
    ind = SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(BLOB_SIZE);
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY,
            SQL_LONGVARBINARY, BLOB_SIZE, 0, &data, 0, &ind))) {
        printf("Failed to bind blob.\n");
        goto cleanup_stmt;
    }

    //Execute
    printf("Inserting BLOB.\n");
    ret = SQLExecute(hstmt);
    if(SQL_NEED_DATA == ret) {
        //send additional data
        ret = SQLParamData(hstmt, 
            reinterpret_cast<SQLPOINTER *>(&paramData));

        if(paramData != data) {
            printf("Warning, data pointers(%p,%p) do not match!\n", data, paramData);
        }

        while(SQL_NEED_DATA == ret) {
            ret = SQLPutData(hstmt, data, BLOB_SIZE);

            if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
                printf("Error setting parameter data.\n");
                goto cleanup_stmt;
            }

            //Read the next parameter requiring data, if any
            /**
             * ===== CRASH HAPPENS ON THIS LINE =====
             */
            ret = SQLParamData(hstmt, 
                reinterpret_cast<SQLPOINTER *>(&paramData));            
        }
    }

    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
        printf("Failed to execute.\n");
        goto cleanup_stmt;
    }
    printf("Inserted blob data.\n");

cleanup_stmt:   
    printf("Freeing hstmt.\n");
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
disconnect:
    printf("Disconnecting.\n");
    SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
cleanup_dbc:
    printf("Freeing hdbc.\n");
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
cleanup_env:
    printf("Freeing henv.\n");
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
exit:
    return exitCode;
}
```

Makefile:

```
blob_test : main.cpp
    g++ -o blob_test -l odbc main.cpp
```

And stack trace:

```
#0  0x00a07363 in memmove () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x001fccbe in _iwrite () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#2  0x001fb431 in _iputpbuf () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#3  0x00184c42 in _Odbcputpbuf () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#4  0x00182cc8 in _OdbcPutChstrNoCsc () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#5  0x00164b4f in _OdbcPutAsfLvarcharVal () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#6  0x001acef8 in _OdbcExtBinary2IntSendrecv () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#7  0x0016ca48 in _OdbcPutBindings () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#8  0x0016c836 in _OdbcAssignInputParams () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#9  0x0016d373 in _OdbcExecute () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#10 0x0014c125 in _OdbcExecuteRow () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#11 0x0014c3a4 in SQLParamData () from /opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
#12 0x00b17f09 in SQLParamData () from /usr/lib/libodbc.so.1
#13 0x08048a16 in main ()
```

And finally, trace from the odbc driver:

```
[ODBC][26114][SQLPrepare.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
                        SQL = [INSERT INTO blob_test(test) VALUES(?)][length = 37]
[ODBC][26114][SQLPrepare.c][364]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][26114][SQLBindParameter.c][193]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
                        Param Number = 1
                        Param Type = 1
                        C Type = -2 SQL_C_BINARY
                        SQL Type = -4 SQL_LONGVARBINARY
                        Col Def = 4096
                        Scale = 0
                        Rgb Value = 0xbfe9a990
                        Value Max = 0
                        StrLen Or Ind = 0xbfe9b99c
[ODBC][26114][SQLBindParameter.c][339]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][26114][SQLExecute.c][183]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
[ODBC][26114][SQLExecute.c][344]
                Exit:[SQL_NEED_DATA]
[ODBC][26114][SQLParamData.c][156]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
                        Value = 0xbfe9a98c
[ODBC][26114][SQLParamData.c][327]
                Exit:[SQL_NEED_DATA]
                        Value = 0xbfe9a990
[ODBC][26114][SQLPutData.c][144]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
                        Data = 0xbfe9a990
                        StrLen = 4096
[ODBC][26114][SQLPutData.c][289]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][26114][SQLParamData.c][156]
                Entry:
                        Statement = 0x9e56060
                        Value = 0xbfe9a98c
```

Am I missing something, or do I have an extraneous call somewhere?

Comment: Not that this helps fix the problem or even necessarily proves anything, but I ran your exact code against another ODBC driver, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I also had success running this against MySQL, so I'm kind of leaning towards this being an informix driver issue. I may have to take a different approach and/or submit this to IBM in hopes of a fix or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

REFER TO: "IBM Informix ODBC Driver Programmer's Manual"
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.odbc.doc/odbc20.htm

Answer (score 0):

In ESQL/C, the data type for a host variable storing a BYTE or TEXT blob is `loc_t`, a structure type defined in a header, `"locator.h"`.  I am not an ODBC expert, but I would expect that you need much the same structure with ODBC too.

Comment: Unfortunately my requirements are to use pure ODBC, whereas locator.h, loc_t, and SQL_C_BLOB_LOCATOR type seem to be specific to informix. (At least they're not available to my test application which only has access to ODBC headers)

Comment: In that case, you are likely to be on a hiding to nothing.  I've not read the Informix ODBC manuals, so there might be something else.  But the driver would have to translate whatever your supply into what the server expects (which means a locator structure), but I don't know how/where the driver does that.